# Question about Weinberg-Witten theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gravity, quantum-spin, carrier-particles

From [Weinberg-Witten theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem), people say that the  [graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) (which has spin 2) can not be composite. But it seems that graviton can still be composite particle by combining spin-3/2 particles. Is there any reason why this is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Weinberg-Witten theorem is used to deduce that the graviton is not composite using the fact that it has spin 2, not the other way around.

Comment: I believe OP is asking what the mechanism (analogous to W-W for spin 1/2 and 1) for preventing gravitons from being composed of spin 3/2 particles is